# Extract User Name from session through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, cookies

I am trying to extract user logged-in name from client side i.e `javascript`. I am able to get cookie that is set at client side which stores current user session id. But how to get user name from that `PHPSESSION ID` ? And i dont want to use any API.
As session is set at server side I am unable to get that information.

Following is what i got, session id by `document.cookie`
Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have to use php $_SESSON to retrieve the name. through javascript it's not possible. Ajax can do it. but ulernativly it uses php only at the end.

Comment: use `AJAX` and avoid questions like this one, try something first.

Answer (score 0):

You might have set username in php global variable- $_SESSION['username']

You can extract this from javascript using the following line.

```
<script>
 var username="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: i want to get session value through javascript  without knowing session name. Just by session id that is set as cookie on browser. Is that possible. Either by javascript or ajax ? And $_SESSION is at server side which needs session name. But i dont know session name.